# How do I change parental controls without pin/call to nintendo

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

My friend gave me a 3DS XL that I want to change the pin on to access the internet and format the system memory.  My friend doesn't know the pin or the answer to the forgot PIN question and I really don't want to call nintendo for  this.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why would someone just give you a 3DS XL? Your scenario sounds pretty dubious.

Comment: It was broken so he had no use for it and gave decided to give it to me.  I fixed it (I just had to fix the charging port and bottom screen LCD) and now I have to get past the parental controls to format it and connect it to my NNID.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you format the system, they will not be able to access their purchases anymore. You may want to do a system transfer instead of formatting once you get the pin reset.

Comment: About that, does the target's NNID get replaced with the source's NNID?

Comment: After the transfer the target 3DS will be linked to the NNID that was previously on the source 3DS. But you don't want there to be an NNID on the target 3DS at the time of the transfer. If you transfer to it, that target's NNID will still be stuck to that 3DS. It can never be used on any other 3DS unless it is transferred first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way of dealing with a forgotten 3DS parental control code is to following the [official guide for resetting the pin](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/493/~/forgot-parental-controls-pin) which does involve contacting Nintendo. Alternatively you can find various tools online that should be able to accomplish the same task without needed to contact Nintendo. One such tool available at this time is called [3DS Parental Tool](http://www.homebrew-connection.org/3ds-parental-tool-remove-the-parental-restricition-easily/).

Answer (score 0):

The 3DS Parental Tool does not work with the 3DS XL, the code you have to input is too long.

I found a link to a tool that worked, and it's online with nothing to download.

https://mkey.salthax.org/

Comment: saved my day, i don't understand why this was downvoted